# Clipping a custom UIView to a triangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

First off, here's an image of my current situation.

[image]

To accomplish this I am using a subclassed UIView with the following method:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint   (ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // top left
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));  // mid right
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // bottom left
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}
```

My ultimate goal is to clip the colored regions so that only the neon green remains. (I'll flip the colors later). I want it to look like a pie chart. I'm guessing there's a way to clip the colored corners out but I have no clue. CGContextClip(ctx) doesn't work.

I am using the Pixate framework as well. If anyone knows a way to accomplish a triangle shape with Pixate that would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to clip a UIView to a path is to create a CAShapeLayer, add a path to the layer, and add the shape layer as a mask of your view's layer.

Comment: Do you have an example on hand of how to do that? Would I create the CAShapeLayer inside my drawRect method?

Comment: Never mind. I was able to get it masking to a square. I think I can take it from here.

Comment: No, if you add a shape layer as a mask, the system clips your view for you. In iOS it's best not to implement drawRect.

Answer (score 2):

Or with a CGPathRef, essentially the same thing but at core foundation level

```
eg..

{

// before existing drawing code..
CGMutablePathRef clipTriangle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint (clipTriangle, nil, startX, startY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(clipTriangle, nil, secondPointX, secondPointY);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(clipTriangle, nil, thirdPointX, thirdPointY);
CGPathCloseSubpath(clipTriangle);

CGContextSaveGstate(ctx);

CGContextAddPath(ctx, clipTriangle); /// this is the essential line I left out, we drew the triangle and forgot to use it, clipping to nothing instead, sorry mate

CGContextClip(ctx);


//draw stuff that you wanted clipped here...


CGContextRestoreGstate(ctx);
CGPathRelease(clippingTriangle); //CFstuff still needs manual memory management regardless of ARC
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this currently and I'm not seeing any results. It just creates the UIView as a rect. It doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Dd you change all the context arguments to ctx as you've called it in your code? Guess you did or it wouldn't compile with unknown argument error..

Comment: Oops I left out a crucial line, slaps head.. Check again I'm editing